# Accessing model that has the same name as a local variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm really confused because i have the following case:

```
Class Game extends CI_Model{
  $this->load->model('user');
  public $user = 'foo';

  $var = $this->user; // Model Or Local Variable?
}
```

How can i tell which one should it use, the Model `User` or the local public variable `$user`?

Comment: Your code is really kind of messed up. But `$this` always refers to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->user` is not the same as `$user`

The model you loaded with `$this->load->model('user');` is only accessable through the `$this` variable. Furthermore, you should only acccess it through the variable scope which the model already is placed in (makes more sense, if you will).

Local method variables, as you're trying to do with `$var = $this->user;`, is only accessable through a method.

So, correcting your code, it would look something like this:

```
Class Game extends CI_Model{

    public function get_player() {
      $this->load->model('user'); // Load the User model

      $user = 'foo'; // Variable with the string value 'foo'.

      $var = $this->user; 
      // $var is a copy of the model you loaded before
      // which means using:
      $name = $this->user->get_username();
      // is the same as
      $name = $var->get_username();

      retun $name;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and fast solution :

```
    If you would like your model assigned to a different object name you can specify it via the second parameter of the loading function:

    $this->load->model('Model_name', 'fubar');

    $this->fubar->function();
```